# Click() function in Selenium not working in Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Here is the website I am trying to scrape: https://www.horrycounty.org/bookings

I have developed a for-loop to cycle through the dates, all I need is to write a simple block of code to click on the "search" button, but I am having some difficulty.

My thoughts are

```py
    search = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-primary')
    search.click()
```

This is my first time using selenium, any help would be welcome.

Comment: What happens when you try that sample code?  Do you get an error?

Comment: I would get an error, "element not clickable at this span", but below Emma and alinajafi resolved the problem! Thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use JavaScript for the click element (that worked for me):

```
search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.btn-primary")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn btn-primary')))
search.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CSS Selector `span.btn-primary` to click on the button:

```
from selenium import webdriver

URL = "https://www.horrycounty.org/bookings"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)

search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.btn-primary")
search.click()
```